# python dictionary evaluates true if key is not present

Tags: python

checking whether a key is present or not but it even though the key doesnt exist the below code evaluates to True.What is the correct and pythonic way of doing this

```
a={u'is_l': 0, u'importance': 1, u'release_id': u'12345', u'company': 1 }

if 'verision' and 'importance' in a: 
   //evaluates to True why ?
```

Comment: `if 'verision' in a and 'importance' in a: `

Comment: read it as `if 'verision' and ('importance' in a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the grouping of expressions would be like -

```
if ('verision') and ('importance' in a):
```

And `'version'` string is `True` in boolean context (Only empty string is `False` in boolean context, all other non-empty strings are True, read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)). , so it short circuits the `and` condition and returns `True`. You want -

```
if 'verision' in a and 'importance' in a:
```

---

For only 2 keys i would suggest the above version , but if you have more than 2 keys , you can create a set of those keys as suggested in the comments by [@Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) and check if that set is a subset of the dictionary keys. Example -

```
needs = set(['version','importance','otherkeys'..])    #set of keys to check
if needs.issubset(a):                       #This can be written as a single line, but that would make the line very long and unreadable.
```

Demo -

```
>>> a={u'is_l': 0, u'importance': 1, u'notes': u'12345', u'created_by': 1 }
>>> needs=set(['verision','importance'])
>>> needs.issubset(a)
False
```

Comment: Is there no other easier way of checking multiple keys rather than this way if 'verision' in a and 'importance' in a:

Comment: The easiest version (for 2 keys) would be this, are you having much more than 2 keys to check?

Comment: For multiple keys: `needs=set(['verision','importance'])` and then you can say `if needs.issubset(a):`

Answer (score 0):

Python adds parentheses for you like this:

```
if 'verision' and ('importance' in a):
```

Since all non-empty strings are truthy, this evaluates to `True`.

If you have more than two elements, it might be better to use `all` with a list:

```
if all(el in a for el in ['verision', 'importance', ...]):
```

Comment: Is there no other easier way of checking multiple keys rather than this way if 'verision' in a and 'importance' in a:

Comment: `all(element in a for element in ('verision', 'importance'))`. This will be more flexible if you don't have fixed values you want to check but a list of those.

Comment: even though i have importance in this case it evaluates to false all(element in a for element in ( 'importance'))

Comment: If you have only one item in a tuple, you must suffix it with a comma: ('importance',). Alternatively, use a list: ['importance']